# how to create a login form using sinatra

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra, rack, slim-lang

I have been looking for info on how to create a simple login form using Sinatra. I have checked the Sinatra documents and I have seen that Rack might need to be implemented which is fine. The code in the document I am talking about is this:

```
require 'sinatra'
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
    username == 'admin' and password == 'admin'
end

get '/' do
   "You're welcome"
end
```

when that is implemented it ask for a username and password to get into the routed page
what I'm trying to do is on the index page there is a form with the normal username and password and submit button once an admin or valid user logs in they get on to the next page which is the app. The form I am using is made using Slim and would be the first page of the app:

```
  form#logger action="/login" method="post" name="logger" 
    tr
      p.logLabel Username
      input type="text" 
    tr
      p.logLabel Password
      input type="password" 
    tr
      input name="login" type="submit" value="Submit"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using user authentication in a *simple* manner is not easy to accomplish in Sinatra. As said by @Patru you can use Warden but the trade off is always a slightly bigger codebase. Using a Rack Auth might be the easiest and cleanest way. Other solutions include OAuth as offered by many of the bigger sites on the internet such as Facebook, Google and the like. Once you start your own solution you will want to use some kind of database for user management. Hardcoded passwords might not be the best solution. A fairly simple solution is what I use in my apps: https://github.com/burningTyger/farhang-app/blob/master/auth.rb Also check out how it is integrated into the app in `farhang.rb`. Just an idea. As a Gist: https://gist.github.com/burningTyger/1443592

Comment: Thanks for the feedback
I was able to get something out of warden and used a sqlite database to store the username and password

Comment: It's best to put a concise code example directly in your answer.  Linking to your github is insufficient, and the auth.rb link has rotted (which illustrates perfectly why code should be directly in the answer).

Comment: That's a joke, right? This answer was from 4 years ago when nothing really useful existed. My answer was not ideal as it involved a database and complicated setup. Nowadays I just use basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Rack::Auth::Basic docs](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Auth/Basic.html) say this Rack middleware is an implementation of [RFC 2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) which describes the HTTP basic authentication. As this is defined on the protocol level it is entirely run by your browser and as of yet it is not possible to add any styling to the dialogs. That is one of the tradeoffs you make if you choose this basic type of authentication (or also Rack::Auth::Digest). Unfortunately with the advent of the BitCoin all the Hash algorithms used in this specifications tend to be "breakable" nowadays given sufficient hardware.

If you desire more flexible (and secure) login procedures I guess you should have a look at [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) which is the Rack middleware powering Devise. That is giving you a lot more flexibility, but as a trade-off it will also involve some more work for you to do. But probably that is going to be the a price you are willing to pay for the added security.

There is also the [sinatra_warden project](https://github.com/jsmestad/sinatra_warden/) which provides some simple guidelines how Warden can be used in sinatra.

Answer (score -2):

I just yesterday finished one of my first web apps using sinatra and it really wasnt that complicated to do a simple login page that validats the username and password. having issues getting the formatting right on here so heres a link to my github its under the webapp repo, any questions just ask its pretty self explanatory though for the most part the validation code starts on the get '/login' https://github.com/josephmckenzie/webapp